# Is there any way to revalidate a server side component in Next Js where I am only querying mongo db to fetch data from it?

Tags: mongodb, next.js13

This is the server side component for fetching and creating objects of certain schema.

```
"use server"
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import Thread from "../models/thread.model";
import User from "../models/user.model";
import { connectToDB } from "../mongoose"

interface Params {
    text: string,
    author: string,
    communityId: string | null,
    path: string
}
export async function createThread({text, author, communityId, path}: Params) {
    connectToDB();
    const thread = await Thread.create({
        text,author,community: null,

    });
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(author, {
        $push: {
            threads: thread._id
        }
    })
    revalidatePath(path);
}

export async function fetchThreads(pageNumber = 1, pageSize = 20) {
    connectToDB();
    const page = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
    const threads = await Thread.find({parentId: { $in: [null, undefined]}}).sort({ createdAt: 'desc'}).skip(page).limit(pageSize).populate({path: 'author', model: User}).populate({
        path: 'children',
        populate: {
            path: 'author',
            model: User,
            select: "_id name parentId image"
        }
    }).exec();
    const totalThreads= await Thread.countDocuments({parentId: { $in: [null, undefined]}})
    const isNext = totalThreads > page + threads.length; 
    return { threads, isNext }
}
```

This is the "/" page or rather http://localhost:3000/ page

```
import ThreadCard from "@/components/cards/ThreadCard";
import { fetchThreads } from "@/lib/actions/thread.actions";
import { UserButton, currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
 
export default async function Home() {
  const result = await fetchThreads(1,30);
  const user = await currentUser();
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="head-text text-left">Home</h1>
      <section className="mt-9 flex flex-col gap-10">
        {
          !result.threads.length ? (
            <p className="no-result">No Threads found</p>
          ) : (
            <>
              {result.threads.map((post) => (
                <ThreadCard
                  key={post._id}
                  id={post._id}
                  currentUserId={user?.id || ""}
                  parentId={post.parentId}
                  content={post.text}
                  author={post.author}
                  community={post.community}
                  createdAt={post.createdAt}
                  comments={post.children}
                />
              ))}
            </>
          )
        }
      </section>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is the '/create-thread" page or rather http://localhost:3000/create-thread

```
import PostThread from "@/components/forms/PostThread";
import { fetchUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.actions";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

async function Page() {
    const user = await currentUser();
    if(!user) return null;
    const userInfo = await fetchUser(user.id);
    if(!userInfo?.onboarded) redirect('/onboarding');
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="head-text">Create Thread</h1>
            <PostThread userId={userInfo._id}/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Page;
```

The problem is I want whenever I create a new thread by going to the /create-thread it should automatically update the "/" route by showing the new threads, but it only happens only if I refresh the page, so is there any way to handle it using revalidate

I tried using revalidate(pathName) but seems to not working and I am not being able to understand the documentation for the same.

Hereby attached PostThread.tsx

````
"use client"

import * as z from "zod"
import { usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Threadvalidation } from "@/lib/validations/thread";
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel, FormMessage } from "../ui/form";
import { Textarea } from "../ui/textarea";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";
import { createThread } from "@/lib/actions/thread.actions";
function PostThread({userId}: {userId: any}) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const pathName = usePathname();
    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof Threadvalidation>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(Threadvalidation),
        defaultValues: {
            thread: '',
            accountId: userId,
        }
    })
    const onSubmit = async(values: z.infer<typeof Threadvalidation>) => {
        await createThread({text: values.thread, author: userId, communityId: null, path: pathName});
    }
    return (
       <Form {...form}>
            <form
                onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                className="mt-10 flex flex-col justify-start gap-10"
            >
                <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="thread"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                        <FormItem className="flex flex-col gap-3 w-full">
                            <FormLabel className="text-base-semibold text-light-2">
                                Content
                            </FormLabel>
                            <FormControl className="no-focus border border-dark-4 bg-dark-3 text-light-1">
                                <Textarea rows={15} {...field}/>
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormMessage />
                        </FormItem>
                    )}
                />
                <Button type="submit" className="bg-primary-500">Post Thread</Button>      
            </form>
       </Form>
    )
}
export default PostThread```
````